Copying data from old column to new column with large amount of records
While updating/copying the data from old column to new column we are facing the issue with tablespaces in database.
Records count: 158 million+
Using below query to update the records,
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NEW_COLUMN = OLD_COLUMN:

I updated the tablespace for the 3 times, but issue is not resolve.

Which problems and how do they sow up error message ?

every time we need to increase the  tablespace if the execution failed.

Can you please suggest the right way to do the copy one column data into another.

what means lage amount of data, varvhar(4000)?

No we have 158 million+ record in a table.

i do know that but i want to know which type you are copying, but even then i can't understand why you are duplicating a column

There is requirement, before the column data type is number(15) now the requirement has been change to number(15,4). We are create new column with number(15,4) and dump the old column value into the newly created column.

What's the exact error - we actually had a similar project a while ago, needed to change a column datatype from VARCHAR2(2000) to CLOB (to release the upper limit of size).  It was quite challenging, and since you can't directly alter VARCHAR into CLOB .. we went with new column .. copy the data .. mark the old column "hidden" .. and renamed the new column.  We didn't have tablespace issues, as we estimated sizes ahead of time, and made sure we had space ... have you done that? (FYI our table was closer to 100 million rows with data in this column, but over 500 million rows total)

as number can used up tp 22 bytes your requirement will be around 3,5 Gigbyte

Recreate the table: CTAS to new table with fixed data, then drop old table and rename new table to old. Add any needed constraints and grants. Segment recreation is vastly faster than doing a mass update of every row.
